# Can I use a vector with the same functionality as a static array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector

just a quick one:

I plan to have an array of AVL Trees (for an assignment, as you imagined - does anyone ever use AVL trees apart from data structures students anyway?) and I was wondering if I could use a nice vector - and take advantage of the for(auto i : vect) c++ 11 functionality.

What I want to do: AVLTree array of 1.000.000 elements so I can check in CONSTANT time if the tree exists or not (array position will be NULL or not)

```
AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks **AVLArray = new (AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks*)[1000000];
for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){ AVLArray[i] = nullptr; } //init everything to null

//do stuff with AVL trees
//...

if(AVLTree[52000]!=nullptr)
{
     cout << "tree exists!\n";
}
```

**Is there an equivalent with vectors**, that will allow me constant time of searching for a tree? All the examples I've seen use vector.push_back() and vector.find() to search.

Comment: yep, do that   std::vector<unique_ptr<AVLTree>> trees;

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Comment: @Exceptyon could you wrap that comment in an answer, maybe provide some short demo code? I'll be happy to accept it as an answer then.

Comment: "does anyone ever use AVL trees apart from data structures students anyway" -- I used to work on an OS that used an AVL tree as the data structure for finding loaded code entities by name (and a few other purposes, but this is the one that motivated including it as a kernel feature). Since lookups are far more common than insertions, it's a more obvious choice than a Red-Black tree. I'm not aware of the grounds on which a hashtable was rejected, though. It might have been because the tree has a better worst case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector` will work because they have an overloaded `operator[]` that guarantee constant time access to the nth element.

But your code is not clear:

```
AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks *AVLArray = new AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks[1000000];
for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){ AVLArray[i] = nullptr; } //init everything to null
```

If you set to `nullptr`, then you need a pointer. Is `AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks` a `typedef` on a pointer ? I assume it is not the case, and that there is a typo -- otherwise you just have to remove this typedef definition to use `std::unique_ptr<TheRealTyp>`. So to clarify, I suppose your code is really:

```
AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks **AVLArray = new (AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks*)[1000000];
for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){ AVLArray[i] = nullptr; } //init everything to null
```

In that case, as suggested you should use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks>>`, and you won't have to initialize it to `nullptr` and the test of nullity changed for a direct "test" of `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks>> AVLArray(100000);

// Do stuff with AVL trees

if (AVLArray[52000])
{
   cout << "tree exists!\n";
}
```

Now, how to use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>>` ?

- Setting a value in the already allocated zone:  `AVLArray[5200] = std::unique_ptr(new AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks));`
- Setting a entry to null: `AVLArray[5200].reset()`
- If you need to add something (the vector will grow): `AVLArray.push_back(std::unique_ptr(new AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks));`
- To iterate over use `for (auto& elem: AVLArray)`. The `&` is mandatory otherwise a copy construcotr is called and `std::unique_ptr` forbids this.

Here a example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// boost
#include <boost/range/algorithm/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>

class A {};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vector;

    vector.resize(10000);

    // Adding some values
    if (!vector[100])
    {
        std::cout << "Adding vector[100]" << std::endl;
        vector[100] = std::unique_ptr<A>(new A);
    }

    if (!vector[1000])
    {
        std::cout << "Adding vector[1000]" << std::endl;
        vector[1000] = std::unique_ptr<A>(new A);
    }

    // Removing one
    if (vector[100])
    {
        std::cout << "Removing vector[100]" << std::endl;
        vector[100].reset();
    }

    std::cout << "Testing element." << std::endl;
    auto printer = [](const std::unique_ptr<A>& elem) { 
            std::cout << "There is an elem !" << std::endl; };

    // use auto& otherwise use unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) that has been
    // deleted)
    for (auto& elem: vector) 
    {   
        if (elem)
        {
            printer(elem);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "for_each element with filtering." << std::endl;
    auto is_null = [](const std::unique_ptr<A>& elem) { return (bool) elem; };

    // Just because I move boost range !
    boost::for_each(vector | boost::adaptors::filtered(is_null), printer);

    std::cout << "end !" << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are indeed correct, it is a typo. AVLArray is a double pointer. Sorry for that. Your answer is clear and demonstrative, thank you very much.

Comment: Uh, another small comment here, how would one go about adding an AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks object to the vector? Using push_back(), I would think, but it looks like I'm messing the syntax up.

Looking for the equivalent of `*AVLArray[10] = myAVLObject;` - myAVLObject initialised/created some lines before.

Comment: I've added information about `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>>` usage in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, mr. Johan. I figured it out myself but your comment also helps.

Comment: Right, final question, I promise:

Now that I'd like to iterate through the vector, what's the best way of doing so using the for(mytype i : vector) structure? Will the iteration go through the 1.000.000 elements or just those that have their unique_ptrS initialised?

I tried `for(auto i:AVLArray)` and `for(unique_ptr<AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks> i : AVLArray)`, both didn't work.

Comment: What  compiler do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::vector` as suggested by Exceptyon:

```
std::vector<unique_ptr<AVLTree>> trees(1000000);
```

by using also the smart pointers implemented in c++11. If your concern is dynamic resizing keep in mind that you can can reserve an initial amount of storage when you create the vector (by passing it as a parameter in the constructor) or via the `resize` member.

If your concern is random access to its objects, rest assured that the [operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) has O(1) complexity.

If you know the total capacity of the container at compile time you could also consider using c++11's [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which provides the same for each functionality as well as the same [constant time access](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/operator%5B%5D/) to its elements.

```
std::array<unique_ptr<AVLTree>, 1000000> trees;
```

Comment: Uh, another small comment here, how would one go about adding an AVLTree_GeeksforGeeks object to the vector? Using push_back(), I would think, but it looks like I'm messing the syntax up.

Looking for the equivalent of `*AVLArray[10] = myAVLObject;` - myAVLObject initialised/created some lines before.